# How to set input validation with $setValidity without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have often heard that $scope is not best practice any more. In any case, we are using the controller as syntax and not even passing in $scope as a dependency.

```
<form name="passwordForm" id="passwordForm">
   <input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" ng-minlength="8" data-ng-model="vm.pwdata.newPassword" required>

$scope.passwordForm.newPassword.$setValidity(*my conditions here*);
```

Of course here I get a $scope undefined error. I have also tried just

```
passwordForm.newPassword.$setValidity(*my conditions here*);
```

and

```
vm.passwordForm.newPassword.$setValidity(*my conditions here*);
```

How can I reference this input?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the form name as the controller instance property.

```
<form ng-controller="theController as VM" name="VM.passwordForm" id="passwordForm">
    <input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" ng-minlength="8" data-ng-model="vm.pwdata.newPassword" required>
```

in the controller

```
this.passwordForm.newPassword.$setValidity(*my conditions here*);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. That actually didn't work for me. my controller is already defined as vm, so i tried vm.passwordForm and {{vm.passwordForm}} just for kicks. But I'm still getting angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'newPassword' of undefined

Comment: Look at your code closer or post more relevant code.

Comment: I did exactly what you said to do.

controller already defined as vm. 

<form name="VM.passwordForm" id="passwordForm">
    <input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" ng-minlength="8" data-ng-model="vm.pwdata.newPassword" required>

this.passwordForm.newPassword.$setValidity()

Comment: If it work for  me and don't work for you that means that you do something wrong.

Comment: Well I am showing you exactly what my code says. I don't post on stack overflow to have people confirm that it doesn't work. I already know that part. Can you make your answers constructive instead

Comment: maybe you could link to your fiddle since apparently this worked for you?

Comment: Hi, here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/62HnDEBE2YZYMwI1Nmcq?p=preview) created for you. Click on the button and see the console. Please note, since the form now attached to controller, you can refer it in your HTML outside the form.

Answer (score 0):

Do u have controllerAs at state/route/template? If yes - use this variable inside of template and 'this' inside of controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.password .....
```